# Как пинговать игровой сервер (и не запинговать его насмерть)?

Tags: facebook, разработка-игр, ping, php, memcached

Есть Facebook-игра на Flash, которая для проверки связи раз в секунду пингует сервер приложения. Суть пинга - писать в БД timestamp когда клиент последний раз был на связи.

Один игрок — один запрос в секунду. Но вот 10 тыс. игроков, и как-то впустую расходуются ресурсы БД, 10 тыс раз в секунду обновляя не особо ценные данные, которым жить меньше секунды.

Пока пришло в голову подключить `memcache` (дело происходит на Heroku), и в нём хранить/обновлять таймеры игроков. Синхрониировать с БД раз в N минут уже. Отдельным worker'ом пробегаться по кэшу, вынимая из него в БД записи игроков, которые отвалились больше 3 минут назад, напр.

Наверняка, есть нормальные/лучшие практики, как поступать с такого рода задачей. Намекните?

Comment: @sergiks, а почему проблема не актуальна?

Вообще, по нормальному, в такого рода играх, клиент должен открывать реал-тайм подключение, таким образом, скорее всего, можно выбросить большую половину костылей в БД, в т.ч. этот т.к., если пользователь оффлайн - вы это сразу увидите (обработка события дисконекта), к тому-же, вы без проблем сможете реализовать, например, рассылку от одного пользователя другим без костылей в виде очередей в БД. В общем, как по мне, PHP тут вообще не к месту

Comment: В этом проекте решилось всё исправлением логики комуникации игры с сервером.

По сути вопроса, это не RT коммуникация, т.к. тут нет одновременной вовлеченности нескольких игроков. Это скорее "проблема счётчиков".

Comment: В таком случае не вижу проблемы в использовании, скажем, redis и полного отказа от хранения таких данных в rdms

Comment: Согласен. Но тут случай когда надо ехать, а не шашечки. Запускать игру как можно скорее в паблик.

Comment: На мой взгляд лучше отложить поездку и потом поехать нормально, чем начать ехать и боятся аварии :)

Comment: Есть два стороны девелопмента: Тёмная и Светлая. И каждая имеет свои преимущества, потому обе до сих пор живы. Переход меж ними тяжёл и не всегда выживает проект, решившийся. И твиттер сначала на руби писался )

Answer (score 3):

Зачем постоянно пинговать сервер?

Если пользователь делает какие-то действия, он по любому обращается к серверу, но не стоит постоянно писать его логи обращений.

Зачем иметь ежесекундное значение Онлайн пользователя на сайте? Кому это нужно?
Мне вот было бы без разницы, для меня +- час это вполне правильное время при большой посещаемости сайта. так что не вижу смысла ежесекундно пинговать просто так сервак и нагружать БД.

Смысл то в игре какой? Грузить сервак значениями когда юзер последний раз был в игре?

Если игра сделана как Iframe то можно подумать и о кеше, но не чаще чем раз в 15-30 минут, иначе смысл кеша как такового, хранение 1 переменной 1 минуту.

Comment: «Мопед не мой», клиенты вот так хотят. Моя задача, чтобы их сервер не упал. 

Игра 2D шутер. Возможно, в ближайших планах полу-интерактив в полу-реальном времени, для чего они и синхронизируют время. На время же завязаны некие ресурсы игры, типа бензобака самолёта.

Comment: чтобы сервер не упал, не нужно его добивать глупыми запросами.

если они не знают слово "оптимизиция" то клиент "Всегда неправ!" в таком случае, и игра постоянно будет вылетать.

10К игроков, постоянно шлют данные на сервак.
Пример:
-допустим 16Мб на php
-процесс апача

итог: 1 сервер этого никогда не потянет, да и 2 тоже, тут их нужно не менее 5-10, с такими запросами + бекапы постоянные, раз нужно реальное время и чтобы все работало, SSD винты для быстроты. ну  и так далее.

>клиенты вот так хотят. 
>Моя задача, чтобы их сервер не упал.

Будет падать!